# Text To Speech Program Closes After Speaking

Tags: python, tkinter, speech, pyttsx3

I am making a text to speech program using PYTTSX3 and Tkinter. Everything works great, except for one thing. Whenever I press the "Say It!" button once, it says the text and quits. Is there a way to stop this? (please come here to help my problem, not just to edit my question) I am on a Mac running python 3.10.2

```
import pyttsx3 as py3
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Say It!")
root.geometry("200x100")

def speak():
    engine = py3.init()
    engine.say(user_input.get())
    engine.runAndWait()
    
label_inst = tkinter.Label(root,text="Enter what you want to say:")
label_inst.pack()
user_input = tkinter.Entry(root)
user_input.pack()
button_say = tkinter.Button(root,text="Say it!",command=speak)
button_say.pack()

root.mainloop()
#Chris L 2022
```

Comment: did you run in cosole/terminal to see if you get error message?

Comment: Don't have the issue when running in my Windows with Python 3.10.3.  So it is platform issue.

Comment: Code works correctly on Linux Mint 20, Python 3.8

Comment: Yeah, closes on my Mac. Do you have an M1? Did you find a solution?